# Power View reports no longer open in SharePoint - "Server cannot be found"

Tags: reporting-services, reports, powerpivot, powerview

I have SharePoint 2013 + SQL Server 2012 SSAS Tabular Mode + SSRS running in SharePoint integrated mode for business intelligence reports. This is in 2 environments, QA and PROD, which are identical AFAIK. All Reporting Services/PowerPivot/Power View services appear to be running in SharePoint.

Power View reports have worked fine for a couple years. However, the PROD environment recently stopped working for Power View reports. If I click on a .bism or .rdlx file, it tries to open the Power View screen (_layouts/15/ReportServer/AdHocReportDesigner.aspx), but then it shows "Server cannot be found. Please contact your administrator". I have enabled verbose logging on SQL Server Reporting Services, and PowerPivot in SharePoint's ULS logs. I then generated the error, and it displays nothing helpful in the logs.

Everything else seems to work okay, including Excel files containing PivotTables connected to the same SSAS data source that the Power View reports are struggling with. How can I do further troubleshooting? I have checked SQL Server logs, ULS logs, Windows Event logs and have not found a single clue for why "Server cannot be found".

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one SharePoint server? Maybe the error gets logged on another one. You can get the logs from all servers of your farm with [ULSViewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020):

[image: ULSViewer-Farm]

You should also try to enable verbose-logginglevel to all SharePoint components. Maybe the error is hidden in another one than you expect.

Comment: This is a simple 1-server farm so I don't think the error got lost. I am hesitant to enable Verbose logging on every component since this is a production server, but I may have to give that a try at some point.

Comment: I do that all the time. Just be sure your maximum ULS-Log size is configured properly to avoid a bloated disk.

Answer (score 0):

Found another thing on google:
http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.de/2014/07/solutions-to-resolve-common-errors.html

Error number 7:

"Server cannot be found. Please contact your administrator." from SharePoint UI. The ULS logs normally will display the real error "The versions of the Reporting Services SharePoint Add-In and the Reporting Services service application are incompatible or don’t support this functionality."

This issue normally related to Reporting Services SharePoint Add-In component on SahrePoint side is different on the SQL database server side. You could verify the version on SQL database side and reinstall the SharePoint Reporting Services SharePoint Add-In using the same installer.